# WCF Web Service with a Singleton COBOL VM

Tags: wcf, service, concurrency, virtual-machine

I have a WCF Web Service that has no concurrency configuration in the web.config, so I believe it is running as the default as persession.  In the service, it uses a COBOL Virtual Machine to execute code that pulls data from COBOL Vision files.  Per the developer of the COBOL VM, it is a singleton.

When more than one person accesses the service at a time, I'll get periodic crashes of the web service.  What I believe is happening is that as one process is executing another separate process comes in at about the same time.  The first process ends and closes the VM down through normal closing procedures.  The second process is still executing and attempting to read/write data, but the VM was shutdown and it crashes.  In the constructor for the web service, an instance of the VM is created and when a series of methods complete, the service is cleaned up and the VM closed out.

I have been reading up on Singleton concurrency in WCF web services and thinking I might need to switch to this instead.  This way I can open the COBOL VM and keep it alive forever and eliminate my code shutting down the VM in my methods.  The only data I need to share between requests is the status of the COBOL VM.

My alternative I'm thinking of is creating a server process that manages opening the VM and keeping it alive and allowing the web service to make read/write requests through that process instead.

Does this sound like the right path?  I'm basically looking for a way to keep the Virtual Machine alive in a WCF web service situation and just keep executing code against it.  The COBOL VM system sends me back locking information on the read/writes which I can use to handle retries or waits against.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web service is now marked as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

From what I understand, this only allows a single thread to run through the web service at a time.  Other requests are queued until the first completes.  This was a quick fix that works in my situation because my web service doesn't require high concurrency.  There are never more than a handful of requests coming in at a time.